# As a new grad student, should I share my self-doubt and fear of failure with my professors?

Tags: graduate-school

I am an international relations grad student in the very first semester..very first course and need some insight.

This may seem a bit overly concerned but I am already terrified of failure. The very first assignment was a discussion on required reading. Its a course that is elective. I could have chosen from several. I found the reading really difficult as it was all about historic theory rather than a specific countrys issue. Its a latam course covering topics like US intl engagement. Upon reading the responses I was shocked at how profoundly great the seemingly more insightful and intelligent the responses were from students further ahead in the program. They literally sounded like phd level academics.

I am hoping to use the masters to transition into second career and have been out of school for 18 years. I have menta health issues and the idea of failing the firSt course would send me into an extremely dark place.

Can I email the professor early on to discuss my troubles and mention my concern and fear. I want to be clear in the email I am not asking for preferential n treatment .. Just insight about what I can do and if other students have been in this position before and what they did.

The discussion was not mandatory with 60% of the class responding ..there are 12 discussions 5 mandatory and 7 where he takes the top 5 ..ive already chosen not to apply to one as I had a panic attack. With half the class not responding I could d glean they also found the material difficult. I could also assume that those who responded were better equipped as based on their advancement in the program

I'm literally on the first weeks assignment and will wait till after the second to seriously consider reaching out.

Is this a horrible idea? One that could be detrimental. He seems open to students reaching out. Please provide thoughts. I'm seriously rattled. I won't perform well with this mindset.

It would be assuring if others found themselves in this situation. I feel incredibly low IQ right now :)

Comment: Please go to the professor’s office hours and chat with her or him. Professors want to help: please avail yourself of this.